# Pretty printing of output in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I am using **pymongo** driver to work with Mongodb using Python. Every time when I run a query in python shell, it returns me some output which is very difficult to understand. I have used the `.pretty()` option with mongo shell, which gives the output in a structured way.

I want to know whether there is any method like `pretty()` in **pymongo**, which can return output in a structured way ?

Answer (score 6):

> I want to know whether there is any method like `pretty()` in PyMongo

**No** PyMongo doesn't provide such method. It is only available in the shell. 
You need to use the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) function from the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pprint.html#module-pprint) module.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can also program it by yourself like:

```
db = connection.[dbname]

collection = db.[yourcollectionname]

for col in collection.find({}):

    for keys in col.keys(): 

        print ('{', keys, ":" , col[keys] , '}' )
```

I think this will be helpful or take it as an option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to print output of pymongo in a structured way.

as the output of pymongo is a `dict`

```
print(json.dumps('variable with out of pymongo query'))
```

this will serve your purpose i think

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit new to this too but I might have found a viable answer for those who are looking. Libraries I'm using are `pymongo`, `bson`, `json`, `from bson import json_util` and `from bson.json_util import dumps, loads`

Where you want to print (or return) try:

```
print(loads(dumps(stringToPrint, indent=4, default=json_util.default)))
```

If your data is already using loads, you will not need loads in this statement.

If you want to use `return` leave out the first parentheses.

Example:

```
return json.loads(json.dumps(string, ..... )
```

If you imported loads and dumps you can leave out `json.`.

I haven't tried (because this worked great for me) to alter the 'indent' value but if you don't like how the output looks, try changing that.

Answer (score -1):

It probably depends on your IDE, not the pymongo itself. the pymongo is responsible for manipulating data and communicating with the mongodb. I am using Visual Studio with PTVS and I have such options provided from the Visual Studio. The PyCharm is also a good option for IDE that will allow you to watch your code variables and the JSON in a formatted structure.