# MongoDB Print Pretty with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, printing, pymongo

I've looked up print pretty for MongoDB, and i understand how to do it from the shell. What I can't find is how to do it with PyMongo, so that when I run it in eclipse, the output will print pretty instead of all in one line. Here's what I have right now:

```
  cursor = collection.find({})
  for document in cursor: print(document)
```

This prints everything in my collection, but each document in my collection just prints in one line. How can i change this to get it to print pretty?

Comment: [Pretty printing of output in pymongo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493535/pretty-printing-of-output-in-pymongo/34497602#34497602). Please  read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34497602/3100115)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

PyMongo fetches the documents as Python data structures. So you can use `pprint` with it like this:

```
from pprint import pprint

cursor = collection.find({})
for document in cursor: 
    pprint(document)
```

Comment: Thanks!! This was what i needed

Comment: If the answer helps, please mark it as accepted answer and upvote if you like.